# What is the difference between the :before_save and :before_update Active Record callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, ruby-on-rails-4

Could someone please explain to me the difference between the `:before_save` and `:before_update` Active Record callbacks in Ruby on Rails 4?

I read through the official documentation on Active Record callbacks, but I couldn't find a granular-enough explanation.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`:before_save` is called everytime a record is inserted/updated in the database. So it is called on every save whether its a new record or existing record.

`:before_update` is called only when the record is updated & never on new record.