# Rails - Get old value in before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-save

I'm trying to get the old value in the `before_save` by adding "_was" to my value but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
before_save :get_old_title

def get_old_title
    puts "old value #{self.title_was} =>  #{self.title}"
  end
```

Both "title_was" and "title" got the new title just been saved.

Is it possible to get the old value inside `before_save` ?

Comment: Are you trying to get old value before you update the same row data?

Comment: yes, lets say my old value was "batman" and changed it to "superman", I want to get "batman"

Comment: Instead of before_save use before_update

Comment: Also read up on [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) and check out the examples

Comment: What you are doing is absolutely correct. can you paste your controller code also.

Comment: @sansarp I changed before_save to before_update and it works now. Create an answer, so I can accept it. :)

Comment: I agree with @architgupta. It seems correct. I don't understand why `before_save` wouldn't work.

Comment: @user2037696 Can you show controller code. It seems you are not calling `save` method inside the controller, rather calling `update` . This is the only reason, `before_save` callback didn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `before_save` use `before_update`. It should work now.

Comment: before_save called at the time of object creation(only one time) and before_update calls every time when object is updated.

Comment: @SachinR you are wrong. before_save is called on update as well as on creation and before_update_is called only on update. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470749/what-is-the-difference-between-the-before-save-and-before-update-active-record

Comment: The answer doesn't give correct answer to the question whether it is possible to get the old value inside `before_save` (it IS) and changing `before_save` to `before_update` is only a workaround for a specific case.

Comment: Did not work for me as `before_update` was called before `before_save` when updating a record, this corresponds to the order in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#updating-an-object. The answer of talal7860 worked well for me, using the `[attr]_changed?` and `[attr]_was` methods of [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Answer (score 13):

The reason for you getting the same value is most probably because you check the output when creating the record. The callback `before_save` is called on both `create()` and `update()` but on `create()` both `title` and `title_was` are assigned the same, initial value. So the answer is "yes, you can get the old value inside `before_save`" but you have to remember that it will be different than the current value only if the record was actually changed. This means that the results you are getting are correct, because the change in question doesn't happen when the record is created.

Answer (score 6):

So, the answer above might work but what if I wanted to get the previous value for some reason and use it to perform some task then you would need to get the previous value. In my case I used this

```
after_update do
  if self.quantity_changed?
    sku.decrement(:remaining, (self.quantity_was - self.quantity) * sku.quantity)
  end
end
```

The _was and _changed? added to any of the columns would do the job to get the job done.

Comment: When writing my tests. I found out that I had to use before_update otherwise, there was no difference between 'quantity' and 'quantity_was'

Answer (score 1):

In rails 5.1.1 ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty provides

```
saved_changes()
```

[Link for saved_changes()](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-saved_changes)
which returns a hash containing all the changes that were just saved.